# Is $\lfloor \zeta(-n) \rfloor$ only prime for $n=23$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, conjectures

I searched for primes of the form of $\lfloor \zeta(-n) \rfloor$, where $n \in \Bbb{N}$,  for a range of $n \le 10^4$ on PARI/GP and found $\lfloor \zeta(-n) \rfloor$ is only prime for $n=23$.

My PARI code:

```
for(n=1, 10^4, if(ispseudoprime(floor(-bernfrac(2*n)/(2*n)))==1, print([2*n-1, floor(-bernfrac(2*n)/(2*n))])); print(2*n-1))
```

Note that $\zeta(-n)$ for odd $n$ (for even $n$, $\zeta(-n)=0$) can be also expressed as:

$$\zeta(-(2n-1))=-\frac{B_{2n}}{2n}$$
where $B_{2n}$ is the $2n$th [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) and written as `brenfrac(2*n)` in PARI/GP.

**Questions:**

> $(1)$ Is $\lfloor \zeta(-n) \rfloor$, where $n \in \Bbb{N}$,  only prime for $n=23$?
>
> $(2)$ Are there finite primes of the form of $\lfloor \zeta(-n) \rfloor$?

I would appreciate any counterexamples(can be a probable prime)/proofs/papers.

Extra: I also searched for primes of the form $\lceil\zeta(-n)\rceil$, $\lfloor\zeta(-n)\rceil$, $\lceil B_n \rceil$ and $\lfloor B_n \rceil$. For $n \le 10^4$:

$(1)$  $\lceil\zeta(-n)\rceil$ seems to be only prime for $n=691$.

$(2)$ There seems to be no prime of the form $\lfloor\zeta(-n)\rceil$.

$(3)$ $\lceil B_n \rceil$ seems to be only prime for $n=14$.

$(4)$ $\lfloor B_n \rceil$ seems to be only prime for $n=38$.

Comment: Interesting question. I am currently running a Mathematica program for $10^4<n<10^5$

Comment: Update: nothing below $1.22\times 10^4$ for the "ceiling" and "floor" versions (other than the $2$ numbers in the OP's post). Had to stop the computations due to unforeseen circumstances. Might continue tomorrow.

Comment: $(B_{2n})/(2n)$ is generally not an integer. What do you mean when you say it's a prime?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The floor function makes it an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it said $|\zeta(-n)|$, not $\lfloor\zeta(-n)\rfloor$.

Comment: Do you have any good reason to look at $\lfloor B_{2n}/2n\rfloor$ ? The Bernouilli numbers are complicated, there are theorems proving modulo and growth properties, most of them are very deep (they fit in the same theory as Fermat last theorem..)

Comment: Very often many properties of primes occur with a $\log\log x$ density hence they give the impression that they are extremely rare or may have finitely many solutions, while in reality there are infinitely many solutions which are appear to be rate because of the $\log\log x$ frequency of occurrence. This may or may not be the case here but we must exercise caution in looking at something about primes. E.g. The smallest prime $p_n \equiv 330 \mod n $ is $p_n = p_{1208198749}$

Comment: If a range is completed for both the "truncate-version" and the "ceil-version" , the "round-version" for the same range can be easily derived from the results.

Comment: Update: $\lfloor \zeta(-n) \rfloor$ has no other prime upto $n \le 2 \times 10^4$

Comment: I think it is very unlikely that you will receive a response to the question "*Are there an infinite number of primes of the form...*"

Comment: @Klangen yes although heuristically I think should be an infinite number of primes of this form as $\sum_{n=9}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\ln \left( \vert \frac{-B_{2n}}{2n} \vert \right)}$ diverges

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha .  For which $M\in \Bbb Z^+$ is it known that there exists $n>1$ such that $p_n\equiv M \mod n$ ?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet In this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197847/find-the-smallest-n-such-that-the-n-th-prime-p-n-equiv-330-mod-n , I found a solution for every $M \le 330$. I would be surprised is there an $M$ for which no solution exists though this is unproven.